# Extend quota for Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My team works with Youtube using Youtube Data API V3 and Youtube Analytics API V2 at the moment.
Our goal is that we using one project(or application) for handling multiple youtube channel.
I know there is a quota for API, but I could not understand the detail about that. Also I can not find how we can extend.

Here is my 2 questions.
First, if we use multiple channel with one project. The useage of quota is calculated by each channel or by project?
Second, is there any guide line or document for extend quota? Is it possible we can extend the quota by payment?

Thanks for the your answer

Answer (score 1):

Skimming the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

- You're right, the quota is complicated: it looks like it's defined to model the load that you're causing YouTube's servers. So in general optimise for reading the minimum amount of data that you need, and make as few separate writes as possible. There's no discussion of per-channel limits: it looks like the limit is per project.
- You can request more quota:

  > Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota on the Quotas tab in the Developer's Console.

  I suspect you'll be asked to describe what you're doing with the API, and based on that they may decide to charge you or not. There is no published pricing that I can find.